# Retrieving the LDAP server you're connected to in PHP

Tags: php, ldap

When connecting to an LDAP server, you can provide multiple hosts separated by a space:

```
$resource = ldap_connect('ldap://dc01.corp.acme.org ldap://dc02.corp.acme.org');
```

But is there a way to retrieve which one is actually being used after a successful bind?

Comment: You may be able to use [`ldap_get_option`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-option.php) with `LDAP_OPT_HOST_NAME`.

Comment: Unfortunately this returns both host names with removed protocols: `dc01.corp.acme.org:389 dc02.corp.acme.org:389`

Comment: Ah, too bad. I hadn't tried it before, but thought it looked promising.

Comment: That is an interesting use-case! What do you need that information for?

Comment: @heiglandreas, I'm using it to display inside my web application so a user will know which AD server they're connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No real good way unfortunately. There is an AD specific way via checking the RootDSE:

```
$con = ldap_connect('ldap://dc1 ldap://dc2');
ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_bind($con, 'user@domain.local', 'correct-horse-battery-staple');

$sr = ldap_read($con, '', 'objectClass=*', ['dnshostname']);
$entry = ldap_get_entries($con, $sr);

// This is the DC we are on...
echo $entry[0]['dnshostname'][0];
```

Comment: Had to look at this again years later. Thanks again @ChadSikorra! Your knowledge in LDAP is insane!